why the request body is null when i pass the body data in Prisma
I use Prisma for storing data in database and i use MySql. this app created by nextjs and typescript. i created the api and it works fine. but when i want to save some data send by api, the request.body is null. when i set the value statically, it stores.


const prisma = new PrismaClient();

export async function GET() {
  const allCenters = await prisma.centers.findMany();
  return NextResponse.json(allCenters);
}

export async function POST(req: NextResponse) {
  try {
    const { name, username, password, address }: any = req.body;
    await prisma.centers.create({
      data: {
        name: String(name),
        username: String(username),
        password: String(password),
        address: String(address),
      },
    });
    return Response.json("done");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return Response.json("error");
  }
}





async function sendHandler() {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        "http://localhost:3000/api/centers",
        newCenter,
        {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
        }
      );
      console.log("Data sent successfully:", response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error sending data:", error);
    }
  }




You have to parse the request body to a JS object before attempting to read the data:

// Note the parameter type
export async function POST(req: Request) {
  try {
    // Parse and wait for the promise to resolve
    const data = await req.json();
    const { name, username, password, address } = data;

    // save
    // ..

    return Response.json('done');
  } catch {
    // ..
  }
}


See the relevant documentation here:
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers#request-body
